# How to call a jquery validation function outside of form

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a validation script I made a while ago. I can pass the script "this" as the form identifier to get it going on the right element (with(this)). But what if I want to call this validation function from a place other than the form itself, let's say, in an another request that wants to know if the form is valid?

```
   function validate_form(thisform) {
        with (thisform) {
            validate_fullName(fullName);
            validate_email(email);
            if (isName&&isEmail) {return true;};
            return false;
        };
    };
```

So basically I want to call this function in another function to check if the form is valid or not:

```
if(validate_form(WHATDOIPUTHERE?)){ // STUFF; };
```

Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `document.getElementById("formId")` (or `$("#formId")` in jquery):

```
if(validate_form(document.getElementById("formId"))){ // STUFF; };
```

For this to work you need to set the id of the form, like so:

```
<form id="formId" method="post" action="...">

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use `id`:

```
function validate_form('formid') {
    with ('formid') {
        validate_fullName(fullName);
        validate_email(email);
        if (isName&&isEmail) {return true;};
        return false;
    };
};


if(validate_form('formid')){ // STUFF; };
```

Comment: Fix your function definition.

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen: could not get that?

Comment: It should be function validate_form(formid) {
    with (formid) {

No quotes

Comment: But this still doesn't quite make sense, because with expects an object, not an id.

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen: now i would simply ask, what is the solution in your eyes?

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen: ok that is why it is chosen one. Thanks for your time